# Why Simple String's Character has So many array Dimensions?

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x, list

I am currently working on a python's String and List.

When I assign string in variable `str="string"` and try to access it first character by `str[0]` it works perfectly and give `"s"`.

But, when I try to find character `str[0][0][0][0][0][0]` it again gives  `"s"`. But when I give `str[0][1]` it gives an error:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Its Correct. My Question is Why Simple String Character has So many array Dimensions? and it did not given any error and print 0 character of string when `str[0][0][0][0][0][0]`. What is Data Structure of String?

My Code is

```
str="string"
print((str[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0])) # Working, but my Question is Why Working
print((str[1][0][0][0][0]))          # Working
print((str[2][0][0][0][0]))          # Working
print((str[3][0][0][0][0]))          # Working
list=["0","p",0]
print(list[0][0][0])                 # Working
```

My Output is:

```
s
t
r
i
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why shouldn't it work?

Indexing a string returns a one element string which is again indexable and returns the same value:

```
>>> 's'[0]
's'
```

since it consists of one element, you can continue indexing the zero-element `[0]` as much as you want.

This is explained in the [standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) section of the Python Reference manual:

> **Strings**
>
> A string is a sequence of values that represent Unicode code points. All the code points in the range U+0000 - U+10FFFF can be represented in a string. *Python doesn’t have a char type; instead, every code point in the string is represented as a string object with length 1.*

<sup><sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup></sup>

---

Side-note: Don't use names such as `str`, you mask the built-in [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str).

Comment: You mean string is made from string, not from char.

Comment: @Artier basically, yes. Python does not have a char type.

Answer (score 1):

In Python a string is a sequence of characters, but characters are 1-char strings.

So if you access `'foobar'[0]`, you obtain `'f'`. Since `f` is however a string, we can access the first character of that string. Since `'f'[0]` is `'f'`. As a result if you access a strings `s` with `s[i][0][0][0]`, you thus keep accessing the first character of the string `s`.

If you write `s[i][1]` however, this will error, since `s[i]` is a one-character string, and thus you can not obtain the second character, since there is no such character.

The string itself is not multidimensional, you simply obtain a new string and call the index of that new string. You can add as many `[0]`s as you like.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in Python, it is due to the fact that you assume there is a `char` type in Python (based on the title of this question).

A string in Python is an array of essentially single element strings. `s[0]` simply returns the **string** `'s'`, not a character. `s[0]...[0]` can be thought of as an infinite recursion that keeps getting the same single element string, *infinitely* many times.

You can go as deep as you want: (in this case, in order to do it more than 997 times you will need to modify Python`s default allowed recursion depth)

```
def string_dive(s, count=0):
    if count < 997:
        count += 1
        return string_dive(s[0], count)
    else:
        return s

print(string_dive('string'))
# 's'
```